# jq how to get the last entry in an object

Tags: bash, jq

I'm working with jq 1.6 to get the last entry in an object. It *should* work like this:

```
data='{ "1": { "a": "1" }, "2": { "a": "2" }, "3": { "a": "3" } }'
result=`echo $data | jq 'myfilter'`
echo $result
{ "3": { "a": "3" } }
```

I tried these filters:

`jq '. | last'  # error: Cannot index object with number`

How can I tell jq to quote the number?

`jq '. | to_entries | last'  # { "key": "3", "value": { "a": "3" } }`

I guess I could munge this up by concatenating the key and value entries. Is there a simpler way?

The tutorial and the manual didn't help. No joy on SO either.

Comment: Doesn't "last" in a JSON object make no sense? The object is an unordered set, and a processor is not required to maintain order. You get an effectively random key/value pair, unless you have some kind of guarantee that the object has its key/value pairs always in the same order. Which would be on top of the JSON definition of "object".

Comment: Don't know about that; the second filter *does* return the last entry – to a point ;)

Comment: If there is an ordering defined, as in "I want the key/value pair for the key that sorts last", then it becomes deterministic, but otherwise, you're at the mercy of whatever produces your JSON and have to hope it doesn't change order on you.

Comment: I realize that, Benjamin. But: all I want is the last entry, no matter how it's sorted. FYI the JSON comes from an entry in my Firefox session containing tab groups, and I'm using the last one as a template for an additional entry. So the data in "last" is not important.

Comment: Then the answer you got should work :)

Comment: Yes, Aaron's answer is the solution. I hope I can understand it when I tackle the resources in the comments!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the following :

```
jq 'to_entries | [last] | from_entries'
```

[Try it here](https://jqplay.org/s/kuq-AMwOdz).

We can't use `with_entries(last)` because `last` returns a single element and `from_entries` requires an array, hence the `[...]` construct above.

Comment: Or very similar, `jq 'to_entries | .[-1:] | from_entries'`

Comment: @TomFenech thanks, made me realise `to_entries | [last] | from_entries` works just as well and is more comprehensible

Comment: Thanks Aaron, that worked a treat! I keep wondering how people can work these out so quick! I found the manual and https://manpages.debian.org/testing/jq/jq.1.en.html#FILTERS overwhelmingly unhelpful. Do you know of an in-depth tutorial that explains *exactly* how jq works?

Comment: @Timm [the online manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) is pretty good imo, but it's hard to remember all the filters so it's probably more a question of experience with the tool

Comment: There is good information in the [jq github wiki](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki) describing the design and how it works.  The [builtin.jq source](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/blob/master/src/builtin.jq) is also worth study.